# Code to update a cell in next column(s) when userform data matches an existing cell - excel vba userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform with 2 textboxes and 1 ComboBox. I want the user to input a serial number in "SN_Textbox1" and the 2nd textbox "RMA_Textbox2" automatically fills in with the matching value (coded and works!)

[image: USERFORM]

After they select the disposition from ComboBox1 and clicks submit... I want to update column 7 in the same row of that matching serial number...

However, it is just adding a new row at the moment...
[image: SheetwithData]

```
'this assigns data to Data Sheet matching serial numbers or adds new values
                
Private Sub SubmitButton_Click()
        
    Dim serial_ID As String
    serial_ID = UCase(Trim(SN_TextBox1.Text))
        
        
    Worksheets("RMA Tracker").Activate
        
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        
        'this assigns data to disposition column to matching entries in serial number column
        
        If UCase(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Text) = serial_ID Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 7).Value = ComboBox1.Text
            
            'Searches for matching RMA & SN 'this assigns data to Log Sheet, if the data is brand new
                
        ElseIf Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Text <> serial_ID Then

            Sheet1.Cells(lastrow + 1, 4) = SN_TextBox1.Text
            Sheet1.Cells(lastrow + 1, 1) = RMA_TextBox1.Text
            Sheet1.Cells(lastrow + 1, 7) = ComboBox1.Text
                
        End If
        
    Next i
        
    'this clears the fields of userform when button is clicked and saves it automatically
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Call resetform
        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
Private Sub SubmitButton_Click()
    Dim serial_ID As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim r As Range
    serial_ID = UCase(Trim(SN_TextBox1.Value))
    Worksheets("RMA Tracker").Activate
        
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 4).Resize(lastrow, 1)
    
    For Each cell In r:
    If UCase(Trim(cell.Value)) = serial_ID Then
    cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = ComboBox1.Value
    GoTo aaaaa
    End If
    cell.Offset(1, 0).Value = serial_ID
    cell.Offset(1, -3).Value = RMA_TextBox1.Text
    cell.Offset(1, 3).Value = ComboBox1.Value
    Next cell
aaaaa:
    'this clears the fields of userform when button is clicked and saves it automatically
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Call resetform
        
End Sub
```

Comment: It almost worked out.... the only thing I'm finding is that new values are only placed in 2nd row instead of the NEXT empty row.... I believe it is because of this `Set r = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 4).Resize(lastrow, 1)` but i don't know how to add this... so it detects the next empty row.

Comment: I changed the `2` for `lastrow` and it worked. Thanks.